# PHP 7.1 on macOS Sierra 10.12.3 - installed by Homebrew

Tags: php, configuration, homebrew, httpd.conf, macos-sierra

I've just installed PHP 7.1 with Homebrew and when I type to Terminal `$ sudo apachectl restart` it returns this message `AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 10.3.1.156. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message` but everything seems to be working well.

`phpinfo();` returns normal results...

`php artisan serve` returns different URL. `http://127.0.0.1:8000` instead of `http://localhost:8000`...

PHP installation steps:

> brew tap homebrew/dupes
>
> brew tap homebrew/versions
>
> brew tap homebrew/homebrew-php
>
> brew install php71 --with-httpd24

In httpd file:

```
LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php71/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so

<IfModule php7_module>
 AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
 AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps

 <IfModule dir_module>
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
 </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

What should I do to avoid this error message?

And how can I get the URL `http://localhost:8000` from Laravel back?

Ok, I found if I add `ServerName localhost` to the httpd.conf (on this path /usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/httpd.conf) the warning is gone - thank you to Andrew

But laravel still return 127.0.0.1... any ideas?
Is it correct installation of PHP 7 on Mac?

Comment: [Here's](http://askubuntu.com/questions/256013/apache-error-could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified-domain-n) something that might help you out. It's for ubuntu, but the problem overall is the same.

Comment: Thanks for reply... but nothing happened. I can try restart computer...

Comment: I edited wrong httpd.conf first time... Thank you Andrew, I add it to this question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After installation PHP 7 `brew install php71 --with-httpd24` run this command `brew unlink httpd24` then edit httpd.conf on macOS Apache (/etc/apache2/httpd.conf)...